# How to turn a pandas-string-based DataFrame to list/tuple based DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have constructed a DataFrame based on CSV files I have loaded.
The dataframe is approx 60 rows and 7 columns. All the objects in the DF are strings at this moment.

This is how it looks now:
[DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xo6Nj.png)

The dataframe will be later on fed into a DNN so I need every object in the DF to be a tuple or a list (I prefer tuple but I would like to have it both ways just in case).

How can I split the values in the string so they will be made as tuples?

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from os import listdir


filepaths = [f for f in listdir("C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/NDVI/data/") if f.endswith('.csv')]
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, filepaths))

df_v = pd.DataFrame(columns=['S2T0', 'S3T0', 'S3T1', 'S3T2', 'S3T4', 'S3T5', 'S2VAL'])
num_columns = len(df_v.columns)
row = 0


while row < len(df)-7:
    temp_data = {'S2T0': [df.iloc[row, 3].replace('[', '').replace(']', '')],
                 'S3T0': [df.iloc[row+1, 3].replace('[', '').replace(']', '')],
                 'S3T1': [df.iloc[row+2, 3].replace('[', '').replace(']', '')],
                 'S3T2': [df.iloc[row+3, 3].replace('[', '').replace(']', '')],
                 'S3T4': [df.iloc[row+4, 3].replace('[', '').replace(']', '')],
                 'S3T5': [df.iloc[row+5, 3].replace('[', '').replace(']', '')],
                 'S2VAL': [df.iloc[row+6, 3].replace('[', '').replace(']', '')]}
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(temp_data)
    row += 7
    df_v = df_v.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)


print(df_v.loc[0, 'S2T0']) #I did this to see the structure of one object in the DF
df_v.loc[:, :] = df_v.loc[:, :].apply(split, ", ")
print(df_v.loc[0, 'S2T0']) #Was hoping the split will work...
```

I get this exception: `NameError: name 'split' is not defined (obviously because this is not the proper use of split..)`

BTW: If you have any more elegant ways to clear the '[' & ']' and construct the df_v than the way I did - I will be happy to hear.

**PLEASE NOTE: Some of my objects are '[]' due to lack of data. I need to pass empty list\tuple or NULL (both are fine)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the issue you're having with split, there is no split *function*. There is a split *method* for strings. What you can do is pass a lambda function and then return each result of applying the method to the string in each row.

Additionally, using `applymap` like below should let you apply the function to all cells in the DataFrame.

```
df_v = df_v.applymap(lambda x: x.split(", ") if x!="" else [])
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I get a list of strings. Any chance we can have it a list of floats?

Comment: You should be able to put normal typecasting into the lambda function: ```... float(x.split(", ")) ...```

Comment: That gives the exception: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Comment: Ok I got it. added this line in addition ```df_v = df_v.applymap(lambda x: [float(item) for item in x])```. Works now. Thanks!